# How to use jquery autocomplete in dynamically form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, autocomplete

I'm having an issue using jQuery autocomplete with dynamically created inputs. I can't get autocomplete to bind to the new inputs.

**Form Table**

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="250px">Nama</th>
            <th width="100px">Kode</th>
            <th width="100px">Harga</th>
            <th width="100px">Jumlah</th>
            <th width="80px"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>


        <tbody id='itemlist' >
          <tr>
            <td><input id='nama' name='nama_input[]' class='form-control' /></td>
            <td><input id='kode' readonly name='kode_input[]' class='form-control' /></td>
            <td><input id='harga' readonly name='harga_input[]' class='form-control' /></td>
            <td><input name='jumlah_input[]' class='form-control' /></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>



        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="additem(); return false">
              <b>Tambah</b>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

**script dynamically created inputs and autocmplete**

```js
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#nama" ).autocomplete({
    source: "get_barang.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#kode').val(ui.item.kode);
      $('#harga').val(ui.item.harga);
    }
  });
});

  var i = 1;

function additem() {
//                menentukan target append
var itemlist = document.getElementById('itemlist');

//                membuat element
var row = document.createElement('tr');
var nama = document.createElement('td');
var kode = document.createElement('td');
var harga = document.createElement('td');
var jumlah = document.createElement('td');
var aksi = document.createElement('td');


//                meng append element
itemlist.appendChild(row);
row.appendChild(nama);
row.appendChild(kode);
row.appendChild(harga);
row.appendChild(jumlah);
row.appendChild(aksi);



//                membuat element input
var nama_input = document.createElement('input');
nama_input.setAttribute('id', 'nama');
nama_input.setAttribute('name', 'nama_input[]');
nama_input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

var kode_input = document.createElement('input');
kode_input.setAttribute('id', 'kode');
kode_input.setAttribute('name', 'kode_input[]');
kode_input.setAttribute('readonly', '');
kode_input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

var harga_input = document.createElement('input');
harga_input.setAttribute('id', 'harga');
harga_input.setAttribute('name', 'harga_input[]');
harga_input.setAttribute('readonly', '');
harga_input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');


var jumlah_input = document.createElement('input');
jumlah_input.setAttribute('name', 'jumlah_input[]');
jumlah_input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

var hapus = document.createElement('span');

//                meng append element input
nama.appendChild(nama_input);
kode.appendChild(kode_input);
harga.appendChild(harga_input);
jumlah.appendChild(jumlah_input);
aksi.appendChild(hapus);

hapus.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-small btn-default"><b>Hapus</b></button>';
//                membuat aksi delete element
hapus.onclick = function () {
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
};


i++;
}
</script>
```

Any advice?

Comment: id's must be unique. every time you run that function you are creating duplicate ids. that's probably why it's not working.

Comment: oke, it's work. but i have problem again when i add row untill three or more. the first row and second row already work, but when i go to third row or more it did not work again? how to create a unique id on each row that is added?

Comment: Thanks bro, this works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS Math functions to create a random and unique id.. then you will need to call the autocomplete inside the function. Just repeat this process for each of your autocomplete methods.

```
var namaid = 'nama' + (Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000));
nama_input.setAttribute('id', namaid);
$("#" + namaid).autocomplete({
    source: "get_barang.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#kode').val(ui.item.kode);
        $('#harga').val(ui.item.harga);
    }
});
```

*Handy tip:* Since you're using jQuery, you can create elements with jQuery a lot easier than in vanilla JS.. have a look at [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/).